# Will my circuit to add status LEDs to indicate VBUS current draw work as intended?

Tags: led, usb, usb-hub, indicator

I am a mechanical engineer with very limited electronics knowledge. Recently I decided to undertake a project to design a USB 3.1 hub for a personal project, to get a better understanding of electronics design and specifically PCB design. I am well aware that I am making my life much more difficult going for USB 3.1 rather than 2.0, however my design is mostly a copy of the TIDA-00288 reference design for the hub controller IC TUSB8041.

I am trying to add LEDs to the board, such that when each USB port is disconnected a red LED lights up and when current draw is detected, a green LED lights up instead. Below is my first draft of the circuit. The hall effect current sensor will output 5V when a current above threshold is detected on VBUS, and 0V when no current is detected. When 5V is output, one mosfet's gate is powered which gives the green LED a path to ground. When 0V is output, the inverter causes the other mosfet's gate to be powered which gives the red LED a path to ground. I would like some feedback on this as I am not totally sure this will work in real life as it does in my head...

[image: First draft of indicator circuit]

Earlier, I was messing about trying to develop a circuit that could achieve the same result but without the inverter or hall effect sensor. I came up with this:

[image: Switch closed represents no current draw on VBUS]
[image: Switch open causes resitive load, represnting max current draw of 500mA]

It seems to work relatively well, albeit I don't really understand how or why. I would greatly appreciate some feedback and any thoughts on what I should focus on learning to design this system.

Comment: Your circuit (without hall-effect sensor) cannot possibly work because you are shorting 5V into 0.1 Ohm resistor, which would draw 50A of current, which is impossible in USB environment. Your hall-effect circuit won't work either because the sensitivity of the ACS722 IC is just 260mV per 1A, and it won't output 5V as you expect.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I see. Do you have any suggestions for how you would implement the circuit?

Comment: To start, you need to realize that there will be no current draw over VBUS/GND loop when a connected device is self-powered.  So you need to re-think your connect criteria. Generally it is impossible to detect USB-A port connection without monitoring USB bus in some non-invasive way and analyze all signals. Or you need to select a different hub IC with "LED status indicator".

Comment: @Ale..chenski thank you for your advice. I have been playing around with using an optocoupler as a non invasive method of monitoring the port.